Yajra Laravel Datatables preventing one column sorting only works when sorting another column
I'm trying to create a datatable as follows but I do not want the first and last column to be printed, sortable or even used for searches but that only works when I click on the sort buttons to sort a different column
Here is my column heads
      <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" id="master"></th>
          <th>User</th>
          <th>Role</th>
          <th>Task</th>
          <th>Agent</th>
          <th>Date & Time</th>
          <th>Action</th>
      </tr>

And here is how I am adding data to the table using datatables
       columns: [{
                data: "id",
                render: function(data, type, row) {
                    return ('<input type="checkbox" class="sub_chk" data-id="' + data +
                        '">');

                },
                name: "Selector",
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false,
                printable: false,
            },
            {
                data: "user",
                name: "user"
            },
            {
                data: "role",
                name: "role"
            },
            {
                data: "task",
                name: "task"
            },
            {
                data: "agent",
                name: "agent"
            },
            {
                data: "created_at",
                name: "created_at"
            },
            {
                data: "id",
                render: function(data, type, row) {
                    return (
                        '<div class="row">' +
                        '<div class="col-6">' +
                        '<a href="/settings/logs/' +
                        data +
                        '/edit" class="text-dark"' +
                        'data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-pen" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>' +
                        "</div>" +
                        '<div class="col-6">' +
                        '<a rel="' +
                        data +
                        '"rel1="delete" href="javascript:"' +
                        'class="text-danger deleteLog" data-toggle="tooltip"' +
                        'data-placement="top" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>' +
                        "</div>" +
                        "</div>"
                    );
                },
                name: "Action",
                orderable: false,
                searchable: false,
                printable: false,
            },
        ],

I expect the first and lust columns not to be sortable by default, but this only happens when I click on another column to sort it. How can I get the no sorting to work by default

You can try to add in columnDefs like in following code:
columnDefs: [
    { searchable: false, targets: [0,6] },
    { orderable: false, targets: [0,6] },
    { printable: false, targets: [0,6] }
]


That only makes the last column to be unsearchable, unorderable and unprintable by default and not the first. You still need to click on another column to remove the search, print and order option from it
